# Explain Python Recursion like I'm 5

Tags: python, recursion

So I found this example of recursion in Python on [W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp), but am having trouble wrapping my head around it.

```
def tri_recursion(k):
  if(k>0):
    result = k+tri_recursion(k-1)
    print(result)
  else:
    result = 0
  return result

print("\n\nRecursion Example Results")
tri_recursion(6)
```

The way I am reading it, with an initial input of 6, the first print of `result` should be 11. `6 + (6-1)`.
What I'm struggling with i think is how the output is being calculated with the continual recursion of `k-1` and what is happening here.

Can someone explain this to me as simply as possible?

Output:

```
Recursion Example Results
1
3
6
10
15
21
```

Comment: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/recursion

Comment: Since the recursive call happens before the print, you see deeper values first.

Comment: At the first iteration, it doesn't arrive to the `print` statement. It calls  tri_recursion(5) before. The first time it can print something is when k=1.

Comment: And even with that, what you believe should be the first value, but actually should be last is nowhere `11 = 6 + (6-1)` but `6 + tri_recursion(6-1)` which happens to be `21`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first call: `tri_recursion(6)` proceeds to the following line:

`result = k + tri_recursion(k-1)`

but it doesn't immediately return and proceed to the `print(result)`.

Because a `tri_recursion(k-1)` call has been made, i.e. `tri_recursion(5)`

This proceeds to the same `result` line and launches a `tri_recursion(4)` call.

And so on until a `tri_recursion(0)` call is made, which returns `0`, failing the `if k > 0` check.

Now the deepest `result = k + tri_recursion(k-1)` which was made for k=1, receives the first returned value and computes the first result, which is 1, and prints it.

It then returns 1 to the `tri_recursion(2)` call which prints 3, and so on.

Answer (score 4):

**Like a 5 year old**

A guy wanted to know his seat row number so he asked the guy in front of him. This guy also did not know the answer so he asked the guy in front of him (convergence) and so on(recursion). Finally the question reached to the person sitting in first row (terminating condition).

Person in first row replies 1, the next guy adds one to it and replies 2 to the guy behind and so on until the first person gets the answer.

```
Ask
  Ask
    Ask
    I am 1
    Reply 1
  I am 2
  Reply 2
I am 3 (Aha moment)
```

---

Now apply this analogy to your code.

```
tri_recursion(6)
  tri_recursion(5)
    tri_recursion(4)
      tri_recursion(3)
        tri_recursion(2)
          tri_recursion(1)
            tri_recursion(0)
            return 0  (Only time in else part, the terminating condition)
          print 1 + 0
          return 1
        print 2 + 1
        return 3
      print 3 + 3
      return 6
    print 4 + 6
    return 10
  print 5 + 10
  return 15
print 6 + 15
return 21
```

Comment: So it effectively creates a break point during the recursion that the execution then regains and begins to work back through the unfinished processes?

Comment: @RichC Yes, that is true for all function calls including recursion. Once the called function returns, callee resumes from the point it left.

Answer (score 2):

Does this help?

```
def tri_recursion(k):
  if(k>0):
    try_recursion_val = tri_recursion(k-1)
    result = k + try_recursion_val
    print(f"At k = {k}, we have tri_recursion(k-1) = {try_recursion_val}")
  else:
    result = 0
  return result

print("\n\nRecursion Example Results")
tri_recursion(6)

Recursion Example Results
At k = 1, we have tri_recursion(k-1) = 0
At k = 2, we have tri_recursion(k-1) = 1
At k = 3, we have tri_recursion(k-1) = 3
At k = 4, we have tri_recursion(k-1) = 6
At k = 5, we have tri_recursion(k-1) = 10
At k = 6, we have tri_recursion(k-1) = 15
```

so as you can see, what we are doing is repeatedly calling tri_recursion with increasing values of k (1 less than k).

Answer (score 0):

The reason you see output like this: to calculate `result = k+tri_recursion(k-1)` prior to print, function will call `tri_recursion(k-1)` — basically, the same function, but with different argument. And it will continue doing so, until it reaches call with `k=0`, where it returns, and chain of results propagates bottom-up.

So recursion idea overall is to have a stack of same functions with different context, and top calls (except for last one) actually waiting for last result, to propagate chain backwards.

I recommend looking into code visualization for non-familiar algos. I.e. http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html

Answer (score 0):

Recursion is a concept which is not natural in the way you would think but as soon as you wrap your head around it you will understand. :-)

The frist print out will be the one from the recursive call which is the furthest (technically the second-furthest) in the onion like structure of all the recursive calls. As soon as k counts down to 0 the function at the end returns 0 to the one above that so that one has the following operation:

```
result = 1+0
print(1)
```

It then returns `result = 1` to the recursive call above it:

```
result = 2+1
print(3)
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

when you call `tri_recursion(k-1)` every time it goes into `if (k>0)` until `k=0`. When in this case it going into else and working this piece of code:

`else:
    result = 0
 return result`

and it returns *result* to prevoius called *tri_recursion* then happening something like that:

`if(k>0):
    result = k+tri_recursion(k-1) # k=1 | tri_recursion(k-1) returned 0 | 1 + 0 = 1
    print(result) # prints 1 and so on`